# Flutter, get value from first touch on slider

Tags: android, flutter

Any idea how to get the value of slider in the first touch. I want to get the distance that the user drags in slider. The initial value can be every value he touches first.The last value i can get from onChangeEnd event.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a variable to hold your Slider's value and this variable will change whenever user drags the slider.
kMinSliderValue and kMazSliderValue are constants defining start and end values of your slider.
An example of how it should be done:

```
SliderTheme(
                          data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                            thumbColor: Color(0xFFEB1555),
                            activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                              inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
                            thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15.0),
                            overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 30.0),
                            overlayColor: Color(0x29EB1555)
                          ),
                          child: Slider(
                              value: height.toDouble(),
                              min: kMinSliderValue,
                              max: kMaxSliderValue,
                              onChanged: (double newValue){
                                setState(() {
                                  height = newValue.round();
                                });
                              },
                          ),
                        )
```